# Creating more than one sequence on object - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I'd like to create different sequences for a model based on a `Selection` field.

Right now I have just one sequence like this:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('mrp.worksheet.contract') or '/'
    return super(mrp_worksheet_contract, self).create(vals)

name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')

_defaults = {
    'name': lambda self, cr, uid, context: self.pool.get('ir.sequence').next_by_code(cr, uid, 'mrp.worksheet.contract') or '',
}
```

But what happens if I want to create more than one sequence based on a field like this:

```
type_prod = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
```

I have the sequence declared on my xml:

```
<openerp>
<data noupdate="1">
    <!-- Sequences for contracts --> 
    <record id="seq_type_contract_code" model="ir.sequence.type">
        <field name="name">contract sequence</field>
        <field name="code">mrp.worksheet.contract</field>
    </record>
    <record id="seq_contract_code" model="ir.sequence">
        <field name="name">contract sequence</field>
        <field name="code">mrp.worksheet.contract</field>
        <field name="prefix">10G-</field>
        <field name="padding">5</field>
        <field name="company_id" eval="False"/>
    </record>
</data>
</openerp>
```

I guess I would have more than one sequence in my xml, but I can't find any example on how to use more than one depend on a `Selection` field.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I have this model, which has a sequence `name` field, what I want, is, depending on which option You select on this field

```
type_prod = fields.Selection([
    ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
    ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
    ('direct','Direct Order'),
], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
help=" ")
```

To create the same record but with a different sequence, for example, if user selects `budgeted` then it's going to be `BO000` and if `nonbudgeted` is selected then the same record is created but with different sequence, it'll be `NBO000` and if `direct` then `DO000`

Comment: what you mean depending on a selection is that when user select a value you schose value from  a specific sequence ?!! can you explain more

Comment: Hi, Thank You, edited my question, check it out please, Thank You again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the record just check the value of your field then select the value from your sequence

```
        If vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
               if vals.get('typo_prod') == 'budgeted':
                      vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('mrp.worksheet.contract') or '/'
               elif vals.get('typo_prod') == 'nonbudgeted':
                      vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('mrp.second_sequence') or '/'
```

I think this will do the job hope you get the idea